# Omit first parameter from functions in a JSON object

Tags: typescript

I am looking for a universal way to achieve something like this:

```
type InputType<T> = {
  increment: (state: T) => T,
  add: (state: T, count: number) => T
}

type ExpectedOutputType<T> ={
  increment: () => T,
  add: (count: number) => T
}
```

Or in other words generic type that mirrors a JSON object, but omits the first argument from functions, while preserving the types of other arguments. (all values are functions in this object).

So far I came up with this not working solution:

```
type OmitFirstArg<F> = F extends (x: any, ...args: infer P) => infer R
  ? (...args: P) => R
  : never;

type ReducerHandler<TState> = (state: TState, payload: unknown) => TState;

type ReducerHandlers<TState> = Record<string, ReducerHandler<TState>>;

type ReducerActions<TState, TReducers extends ReducerHandlers<TState>> = Record<
  keyof TReducers,
  OmitFirstArg<ReducerHandlers<keyof TReducers>>
>;
```

This is what I test it with:

```
function get<T>(input: ReducerHandlers<T>): ReducerActions<T, ReducerHandlers<T>> {
  throw new Error("Not implemented");
}

type CounterType = {
  counter: number;
};

const counter: ReducerHandlers<CounterType> = {
  increment: (state) => {
    state.counter++;
    return state;
  },
  add: (state, count: number) => {
    state.counter += count;
    return state;
  }
};

const input: ReducerHandlers<CounterType> = {
  increment: (state) => state,
  add: (state, count: number) => state
};

const output = get<CounterType>(input); // never
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `OmitFirstArg` seems to be fine, but you need to [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) it over the properties of your object:

```
type OmitFirstArgFromMethods<T> = { [K in keyof T]:
  T[K] extends (x: any, ...args: infer P) => infer R ? (...args: P) => R : T[K]
}

type ExpectedOutputType<T> = OmitFirstArgFromMethods<InputType<T>>
/* type ExpectedOutputType<T> = {
    increment: () => T;
    add: (count: number) => T;
} */
```

By using `Record` instead of a mapped type where you act on each property in turn, you're basically throwing away the relationship between the keys and the values.

---

I'm not sure how to use your test code, though.  If `get()` is supposed to take an object full of methods-of-at-least-one-argument-of-the-same-type, then you can use a recursive [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to guarantee that `input`'s properties are all methods of at least one argument, and where the first argument to each is the same type:

```
function get<T extends { [K in keyof T]:
  (state: Parameters<T[keyof T]>[0], ...rest: any) => any
}>(input: T): OmitFirstArgFromMethods<T> {
  throw new Error("Not implemented");
}
```

Then your `counter` should have its type inferred, not annotated, since you don't want it to forget that the keys are named `increment` and `add` (I assume):

```
const counter = {
  increment: (state: CounterType) => {
    state.counter++;
    return state;
  },
  add: (state: CounterType, count: number) => {
    state.counter += count;
    return state;
  }
};
```

And then finally the typings work as I think you want:

```
const output = get(counter);
output.add(123).counter; // okay
output.increment().counter; // okay
```

While preventing "wrong" inputs:

```
get({
  foo: "oops" // error, string is not assignable to function
})

get({
  bar: (x: string, y: number) => 1, // error, string | number is not string
  baz: (x: number) => 2 // error, string | number is not string
})
```

I'm not 100% sure how you plan to *implement* `get()`, since it needs to pass to the methods of `input` a value it doesn't necessarily have.  Perhaps `get()` should also accept a value of type `Parameters<T[keyof T]>[0]`?

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdmArsAKuCAeFA+KBeKAbwCgooBLOAYwCcIBbCOYALigAoBnYAQ2AjYoAlPlwoANKSg8AJjLZde-QeKhUA9omZs4iegCMINEXjHEAvsWKhIUAPL1ywAGLka3AII0A5s5rr6AFkIYAALdRlOLFwCQigAbQBpCjgoAGsIEHUAMygUAF0WKRQk-KgIAA9+OEiOCrYeOBBVADo2nh9ONkpsoygABRNcHr6AJSgAfg42lo7vLoGhqHHBUosrG2gAUQrIKn4ZO2QkVHRo-HtHFzdPHz8A4LCIqPgTtEho7GIAegAqKE2UB2ewOR2AbzOOAuJDIZEotAYTFYHCWKAA3FIyLJ5BwNFpkboDEZURjzFBft8rNktPtyOpUt4QlhylUmLU4kkUulMjk8oUpIo+AIBh0eIx+O4sPEMllcgVsPEAAz5VptOjcBpNJaNEAWbDsSgnQRCNgOJyudzALy+fxBELhSLnGEA0L+ADuUDgEA9Wxo-ho7AARAA5dTACj0MAAG0RzAgMkDQlJG3QUAAwpo4zR3tBYlI8VmdHpDDRSRjiBo4Nw1JmJdCpPC6IxtBxuEK2Bn8UYc0tnWQ2-wWgWJQBqEcY2FQOjARA0VIDiATqDmSRYuQKBcd2vd9CqYdFonGURETFQBdD7c0KAjgjDpdkaez+dKRdSSzmcuV6uacHIC6M4B2GHYkMR-E5ZjkdgAEYACYAGYhAvLtSygb5vigdQ0h4XUwOQFpG1jQDEOAlC0IwrDdWIAD2GdbJ1HUNhA3osBOEDVD0KMf1VG4GhKG8ChOE9MNpE4ThyG8OAeH0GMAXUKBqWoYA6TgCwhCsajnX0DoFHqM9gF4uBvFUEADxLJYoNUMjOPUGhuP0vioAAH09Ys+nIQS4GEni+KkLSAC8dNM4ljxg9jyj9Gy7IM-jnMJEsBKE8NvMM1SgA)